# How to return-7-6-5-4-3-2-1012345678910111213

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Code below is in Objective C in Xcode. I am trying to return -7-6-5-4-3-2-1012345678910111213 as the method is expecting that response. number = -7 and otherNumber = 13 How do I return the series of numbers? I tried the method below but with no success...

```
while (number < otherNumber) {
    ++number;
    return number;
}
```

Comment: you can't return multiple times within a method. you need to store your numbers in an array and return all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look out for is how your parameters are getting passed in to the method. Since we dont know if "number" is always going to be less than "otherNumber" you should check to find out which of the two numbers being passed in is lower before using them in your while loop.

this is very similar to the previous post but it might make it a tad clearer:

```
//find which number is low and which is high and set it accordingly
while (low <= high){
    //then append low to end of string
    ++low;
}
//return your string
```

And this handles the case when the numbers are equal

Comment: I still dont understand..... I dont have a problem getting the parameters passed into the method. My problem is trying to return a string that can take the value of number and otherNumber, and then return those two numbers with the numbers in between them included as well..

Comment: After a lot of googling, I finally found my solution :) Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

In Objective-C, methods can only have one return value.

If your method returns an array, something like this would work:

```
// Create an NSMutableArray

while (number < otherNumber) {
    // Add the number to the array
    ++number;
}

// Return the array
```

Or, similarly, if your method returns a string:

```
// Create an NSMutableString

while (number < otherNumber) {
    // Append the number to the end of the string
    ++number;
}

// Return the string
```

A few notes:

- your conditional, `number < otherNumber`, won't capture the case where `number == otherNumber`. Since in your example `otherNumber` is 13, and you want that included, you may want to use `number <= otherNumber`.
- you can only compare scalar numbers (like `NSInteger` or `CGFloat`) with the inequality operators (like `<` and `>`). However, you can only add objects to NSMutableArray and NSMutableString. So you'll need to convert between the scalar numbers and `NSNumber` as appropriate.

Since it looks like you're learning Objective-C, note that this is different from Swift, which *does* allow methods to return multiple values.